# How to SSH to an ip:port using PuTTY in Windows?

Tags: ssh, putty

I want to SSH to a server over a specific port using PuTTY in Windows.  When i try the same using following command, it works fine :

```
putty -ssh userid@10.125.34.25 -P 9201
```

But i want to try the same thing using GUI. Can anyone tell me how to specify the '-P' option (as in above command) using the putty gui version. I tried to specify this as "10.125.34.25:9201", but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the port in the field that is labeled "Port".

[image: screenshot]